# error submitting multiple checkboxes

Tags: java, jsp, session, checkbox, scriptlet

I am using this scriplet within my jsp:

```
<%
    String q3 = request.getParameter ("checkbox1");
    session.setAttribute("q3", q3);
%>
```

This will get the values from these checkboxes

```
<p> Which of the following are associated with Threading? Select two </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="LiveLock">LiveLock<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Stack Overflow">Stack Overflow<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Heap">Heap<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Starvation">Starvation<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Next" >
```

Or rather..thats what it should do. But when i grab the values and print them out as so

```
<p>Good day <%= session.getAttribute("uname") %> </p>
<p>For question 1 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q1") %> </p>
<p>For question 2 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q2") %> </p>
<p>For question 3 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q3") %> </p>
<p>For question 4 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q4") %> </p>
```

The radio buttons for q1,2,4 work fine. the check box will only return the first value that is checked or rather. The value that comes first i.e. if i select "Heap" and then "Livelock", in the print outs it will display "LiveLock"

Comment: another moron on here down voting perfectly reasonable questions. i dont understand something, I ask a question to a community where someone is bound to know the answer. oh look, two people who commented below both helped a lot. then some classless, gutless, moronic, supine, invertebrate idiot down votes for no good reason. SHOW YOURSELF COWARD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [request.getParameterValues()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) instead of [request.getParameter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) because checkbox names are same.

Remember that `getParameterValues()` returns array so you have to do

```
  String q3[] = request.getParameter ("checkbox1");
```

and for retrieving values iterate it like below

```
for(String s:q3)
{
System.out.println(s);
}
```

for printing in the browser

you can do

```
for(String s:q3)
    {
    out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont want to syso it, i need it to print in the browser like the radio buttons have

Comment: @RedBaron  you can use out.println() for printing in the browser

Comment: cool, think we are almost there. only problem is where i need to put the "out.println(s)" is on a different page to the checkbox and for some reason it will not recognize the q3 variable (underlined in red).
For question 3 you chose <% for(String s:q3)
    {
    out.println(s);
    } %> </p>

Comment: @RedBaron keep String q3[] = request.getParameter ("checkbox1"); as well as for(String s:q3)
    {
    out.println(s);
    }
 in the same page.It will print all the 4 values.

Comment: i understand how that works. just my issue is that I have a results.jsp file where all the users answers are shown. Currently with this method it prints the results on the next page (the wrong page). i need to do the out.println on the results.jsp but if i do that then the jsp does not recognize the variable. do you see the issue?

Comment: @RedBaron how many pages do you have?what is the question page,what is the answer page and where do you want to show the results.Mention everything in clear,

Comment: i have 4 jsps which have questions and answers on them. 3 with radio buttons and 1 with a check box. each jsp has a next button which just goes to the "next" jsp. (as determined by the form inside it). on the final question page, the next button goes to a result page (also a jsp). on this page for the radio buttons there is syntax like this <%= session.getAttribute("q1") %> which gets the answer the user picked from the radio button. so i need to get the checkbox one to be able to do the same. does that make sense or is further clarification needed? can post code in question if helps

Comment: @RedBaron this is a bad idea to keep radio button values in session.Give different names to the check boxes(Now you are giving same name)so now you set different attributes and get the respective attributes.If you dont want to do change the checkbox names then keep the whole array in the session like session.setAttribute("q3",qrarray) and when you retrive then it will be in array type

Comment: why is it back to keep radio button values in session? is there a better way?

Comment: but session is the only way to complete it. plus google didnt seem to return any results suggesting session shouldnt be used...

Comment: @RedBaron no session is not the only way,There are many ways but for that I have to completely understand your scenario.May be next time when I am free I will explain.

Comment: sounds good. tbh session might be just quick a "quick fix" for now. pm me if you get a chance to explain, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.getParameterValues` to get multiple checkbox selection:

```
String[] q3 = request.getParameterValues ("checkbox1");
```

Store in session:

```
session.setAttribute("q3", request.getParameterValues("checkbox1"));
```

Traverse to display values:

```
<p>Good day <%= session.getAttribute("uname") %> </p>
<p>For question 1 you chose 
    <%String[] ans = (String[])session.getAttribute("q3");
    for(String chkd : ans) {
        out.print(chkd);
        out.print(", ");
    }%>
</p>
```

Note: use of scriplets are not recommended.

Comment: thanks. i just tried that and imagine it does work but on display i got this: [Ljava.lang.String;@59ffea71
for radio buttons it says: For question 2 you chose Liskov Replacement Principle
for checkbox it says: For question 3 you chose [Ljava.lang.String;@59ffea71

imagine i have to convert to a string, any ideas?

Comment: almost there, just unsure how to out.println on the desired page. see comments for other answer below